# Does the category of G-spectra know G?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ring-spectra

I was recently in the situation of having access to the category of $G$-modules (for some group $G$ which I had forgotten), as just a category, i.e. **no monoidal structure**, together with the forgetful functor to $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, and wanting to reconstruct $G$.

Alas, I could only reconstruct $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ (as endomorphisms of the forgetful functor), and apparently, [there are groups](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3062112) $G$ for which $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ does not know $G$.

In principle, I could learn what a spectrum is and work with those instead --- would it help? I.e.,

> Does the category of $G$-spectra (together with the forgetful functor to spectra) know $G$?

Comment: A spectrum is a topologist's abelian group, so the result is similar: you can only learn the stabilization $\Sigma^\infty G$. If you need $G$ itself, then a better choice would be the unstable equivariant category of $G$-spaces, but even then I am unsure if you can reconstruct $G$ itself and not just its homotopy type. You can probably do it for compact groups, but I don't have a reference.

Comment: What kind of $G$-spectra are talking about here? I know at least three types..

Comment: I think that the question *might* have an affermative answer for genuine $G$-spectra (a.k.a. spectral Mackey functors) although the lack of a monoidal structure worries me a little (also I'm assuming that $G$ is a (pro)finite group here, or at least some kind of compact Lie group because otherwise I don't know how genuine $G$-spectra are defined)

Comment: @AntonFetisov : but what is the stabilization of G?  How do you know it doesn't know G?  (Finding a finite group counter example to Z[G] knows G took 60 years or something)

Comment: @Vivek: explicitly it's the suspension spectrum, and heuristically it's the "group algebra over the sphere spectrum." No idea how to show it doesn't know $G$ (as an $E_1$ space; that's the best we can hope for), but it at least doesn't obviously know $G$.

Comment: Re. the question of "why not use some nonabelian coefficients like all $G$-spaces", the point for me is that my access to the category of $G$-modules comes via constructible sheaves on a space with fundamental group $G$.  Of course, one can take constructible sheaves with nonabelian coefficients.  However, I need to use microlocal techniques in sheaf theory, which fundamentally depend on the ability to take cones, shifts, etc.  Thus, I need to use coefficients which allow this; ergo, spectra rather than spaces.

Comment: I think that if you define $R_G=\Sigma^\infty_+G$ in the most obvious way as an orthogonal ring spectrum, then ring maps from $R_{\mathbb{Z}}$ to $R_G$ biject with $G$, so $R_G$ knows $G$.  However, this is not so relevant because the category of $G$-spectra only determines the cofibrant replacement of $R_G$ in the category of rings in orthogonal $G$-spectra; that's an extra wrinkle that one has to worry about.